# getHeight() and constants (java)

Tags: java, variables, graphics, constants

I have written code that uses the width and height of a screen in GraphicsProgram to draw boxes, in which I do other things. These boxes will be 1/6th of the vertical size of the screen (the height).

The way I have it now is in my run method I make a variable like this:

```
int boxHeight = getHeight() / 6;
```

Which I then move to other methods like this:

```
placeBox(boxHeight);
```

And in my placeBox method I get that variable like this:

```
private void placeBox(int boxHeight) { ..code.. }
```

It all works, but I was wondering if it were possible to instead use constants, which I would declare before my run method like this:

```
private static final int constantBoxHeight = getHeight() / 6;
```

However this gives me the following compiler error:

```
non-static method getHeight() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

So my questions: am I implementing the constant the correct way?
If not, how do I implement it correctly?
Also, if what I am trying to do is even possible, what is the advantage of using constants instead of moving my variables from my run method to methods inside it which then moves it to other methods inside it?

getHeight() is imported from acm.graphics.*

Comment: What don't you understand about the error you get? Have you looked it up?

Comment: When you declare a static variable, it's a variable of the class, not the current object. So if you were to call `getHeight()` in the class and not the instance, and if this could work (which it doesn't) which instance's height would you be trying to get? It doesn't make sense to do this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So what I should do is declare the constant within my run method like this: 

  final int bH = getHeight() / 6;
Is this way better than moving variabels like I did before this?

Comment: You said you have a solution that works, so why do you want to change it? What's the advantage of making it a constant, besides learning new compiler errors?

Comment: @Holger because if I have a constant I do not have to write newMethod(variable) and in that method newMethod(type variable). It saves a lot of writing.

Comment: But you have already written that method. And now you are going to write even more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant is a static field but you initialize it with a value derived from the return value of an instance method. Instance methods require an instance. Static fields don't belong to instances and can therefore not be initialized with instance methods.

As long as you don't have another way to get the height you will need an instance of that class first. I would personally not use a constant in this case because there are no (or at least very few) downsides of refactoring the code and using an instance member or a local variable.

Comment: I will do that, thank you.
You mention that in different cases there might be downsides. Could you perhaps give an example?

Comment: As I said, there are very few disadvantages. For example, the JVM will occupy 4 additional bytes of memory (+ overhead) per instance and a one-time calculation saves resources - in theory. You see, none of these points matter in your case. You might use an instance variable (as you suggested in a comment) or calculate the height in a new method.